# SQL - cannot compile body of <package> without its specification

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Trying to create a package that will do a calculation: A procedure holds a variable with a number, I will then call the package along with the variable, and a calculation will be made and printed out. However I get that the "my_pkg is invalid" and "cannot compile body of  without its specification"
Any input is much welcome

```
create or replace package my_pkg as
Procedure do_calc(v_add number);
v_sum number;
v_number number;
end my_pkg;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg as
Procedure do_calc (v_add number) is
v_sum number;
v_number number;
begin
v_number := 10; 
v_sum := v_number + v_add;
dbms_output.put_line('sum is: '||v_sum);
end do_calc;
end my_pkg;
/
```

Comment: I can compile the package and body as provided in the question without errors.

Comment: The code provided compiles fine. Just make sure you compile the specification before the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the variables you declared in the package as they are not necessary. Variables you use in a procedure can be declared in the package but then they are global to the anyone with execute on the package.  Also, as a tip, do not declare variables with the same name that are in different scope in the same package, it makes it hard to debug.

```
create or replace package my_pkg as
Procedure do_calc(v_add_in number IN);
--v_sum number;  --you don't need these, they are internal package variables
--v_number number;
end my_pkg;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg as
Procedure do_calc (v_add_in number IN) is
v_sum number;
v_number number;
begin
v_number := 10; 
v_sum := v_number + v_add;
dbms_output.put_line('sum is: '||v_sum);
end do_calc;
end my_pkg;
/
```

Comment: While those lines are not necessary, they shouldn't prevent compilation either.

Comment: How about adding some explanation? What did you change (apart from commenting out the package variables) ? Why did you change it?

Comment: removing the v_sum etc etc solved it for me! thank you!